# Connecting to SQS with JMS using Java 1.6

Tags: jms, amazon-sqs

I get an "Unsupported major.minor version 51.0 error" when connecting to SQS using the AWS's JMS SQSConnectionFactory in Java 1.6.  It works in Java 1.7

I have not found any documentation which specifically says that it is imcompatible with 1.6  Has anyone managed?  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it's compiled for Java 7.

You can download source code and compile it for Java 6.

https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sqs-java-messaging-lib

You will probably need to do few changes in source code, for example remove diamond operator `<>` from some tests.

When you open the page mentioned above, there is Minimum Requirements in README.md which specify that minimum version of java is 7.

Answer (score 0):

For those who still looking for solution with Java 6, here what worked for me on IBM Domino 9 server, which was still running with java 6.
Hope it may help you to move further.

I've downloaded an old sdk version 1.11.664 (and it's dependancies) from [maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk/1.11.664).

Put jar files to /jvm/lib/ext folder:

> joda-time-2.8.1.jar 
> httpcore-4.4.11.jar 
> httpclient-4.5.9.jar 
> aws-java-sdk-sqs-1.11.664.jar 
> aws-java-sdk-1.11.664.jar 
> aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.664.jar 
> jmespath-java-1.11.664.jar

Add permissions to the end of java.policy file:

> grant { 
> permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "getenv.AWS_PROFILE";
> permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "getenv.HTTPS_PROXY";
> permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "getenv.https_proxy";
> permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "getenv.AWS_CSM_ENABLED";
> };

Sample code is below (some vendor specific parts removed):

```
package com.javasix.awssqs;
 
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSStaticCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQS;
import com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.Message;
import com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.SendMessageRequest;
 
import java.util.List;
 
public class SendRecieveMessages {
      private static final String ACCESS_KEY_ID = "ACCESS_KEY_ID";
      private static final String SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = "SECRET_ACCESS_KEY";
      private static final String QUEUE_NAME = "QUEUE_URL";
 
      public static void main(String[] args) {
 
            BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials(ACCESS_KEY_ID,
                        SECRET_ACCESS_KEY);
 
            final AmazonSQS sqs = AmazonSQSClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(
                        Regions.US_EAST_1).withCredentials(
                        new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCreds)).build();
 
            // Send message
            String message = "Java 6 test message";
            SendMessageRequest sendMessageStandardQueue = new SendMessageRequest()
                        .withQueueUrl(QUEUE_NAME).withMessageBody(message)
                        .withDelaySeconds(5);
            sqs.sendMessage(sendMessageStandardQueue);
 
            // receive messages from the queue
            List<Message> messages = sqs.receiveMessage(QUEUE_NAME).getMessages();
 
            for (Message m : messages) {
                  // Do something with your message here
 
                  // delete messages from the queue
                  sqs.deleteMessage(QUEUE_NAME, m.getReceiptHandle());
            }
      }
}
```

That allowed me to connect to AWS SQS.